# Why do i get array foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello can someone explain me why i'm getting an array in this code?

```
$loop2 = $link->query("SHOW tables FROM test");

$tables = $loop2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($tables as $table) {
        $capital = $table;
        $small = $table;
```

when i echo `$capital` or `$small` i get (Array) why is that? i'm using foreach by the way sorry i'm a newbie

Comment: $capital = $table['field_name];

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` tells it to fetch each record as an associative array.  So `$tables` is an array of records, and `$table` is an array of values within a given record.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra This time i'm getting null nothing when i run the script i want to get the table names printed on option tags

Comment: @David and how can i get the table names to loop in a string? like i said in the top i want to loop inside option tags

Comment: @J.Code What happens when you `print_r($table)`?  What is the structure of what that query returns?  All you have to do is output the element of the array that you want, but you need to know what elements it has.

Comment: `print_r($table)` returns me all my tables in the test db

Comment: `print_r($tables)` might get you _all_ the rows in the results (and all the values within each row). But `print_r($table)`, when executed within the foreach, should show you the fields within _one row_ of the results. I don't see how print_r($table) could possibly be showing you _all_ the tables. Double-check what you wrote.

Comment: P.S. If you want to make it so that we can all stop having to guess what you mean, please **show us** the content of what that query returns. The output of `print_r($tables)` would do the job. Even just the first couple of items from the array will do as a sample. Once we can actually see your data it will be much easier to give you a definite answer about what to do. Also...you say you want to put this into option tags...which fields from the table do you want to use for the value and the description in each tag? You didn't mention it.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop `$table` is an associative array which  contain items (table columns names) from your selected table,  like as below

```
$table['column_id'];
$table['column_name'];
$table['column_date'];
```

You can further check it columns by using `print_r()` php function

```
print_r($table);
```

Comment: still getting null when i use `$table['column_name'];` i have no value option tags are blank

Comment: @J.Code `$table['column_name'];` is an example. You must `print_r($table);` to know about columns name

Comment: How am i going to make a loop with each? i want all the tables to be looped i can see my tables

Answer (score 1):

I thinks, It's a associative array, please try `print_r` to check the associative and then use another one foreach loop and try again.

```
$kmg = array('val1'=>array('1','2','3'),
            'val2'=>array('4','5','6'));

foreach($kmg as $value){
    print_r($value);
}
```